# Find common elements to multiple vectors

Tags: r

I have these vectors with character: the main features are that they have diffferent length. My original vectors a much bigger than these:

```
   a<-c("a","b","c","E","L")
    b<-c("E","L","f","b","q","u")
    c<-c("a","E","b","L")
    d<-c("b","a","a","E","g","h","L")
```

How do I implement a routine that makes it find all the letters that belongs to all the vectors on the same time:

The final output should be :

```
final<-c("E","L")
```

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, list(a, b, c, d))` ?

Comment: `"b"` is in every vector too I think.